# Is there a way to get a dict object with nonlocal variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was wondering, is there a function in Python that returns a dict object that contains nonlocal variables used in enclosing functions? Like `vars()` or `locals()` for local variables or `globals()` for global ones.

Update:
As thebjorn noted, nonlocal variables that are *actually used* in the nested function are included in the `local` list. On 3.2.3 the following code

```
>>> def func1():
...     x=33
...     def func2():
...             # Without the next line prints {}
...             print(x)
...             print(locals())
...     func2()
... 
>>> func1()
```

returns `{'x': 33}`.

Comment: A quick test suggests that `nonlocal` names are included in `locals` in Python 3.3, what version are you using?

Comment: No, they're only included in locals if they're used locally...

Comment: @delnan I'm using 3.2.3. In this version `locals()` returns `{}` if used inside a nested function.

Comment: Please show the program that you used to determine this, because unless ideone.com is lying to me, it *does* work in 3.2.3 too. I suspect your test is flawed.

Comment: `locals()` only returns locals and _free_ variables. If you have a non-local that isn't free in your inner function (i.e. you're not using it), then `locals()` will not list it.

Comment: If you add `print(x)` inside `func2`, then locals will return it..

Comment: @delnan I updated the question, appending the code of the function. Maybe I made a mistake somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no builtin `nonlocals()`, but you can create one yourself:

```
def nonlocals():
    import inspect
    stack = inspect.stack()
    if len(stack) < 3: return {}
    f = stack[2][0]
    res = {}
    while f.f_back:
        res.update({k:v for k,v in f.f_locals.items() if k not in res})
        f = f.f_back
    return res
```

if i run it on your program I get:

```
{'func2': <function func1.<locals>.func2 at 0x0000000002A03510>, 'x': 33}
```

Comment: This won't work in IronPython without the command line option `-X:FullFrames`, which will hurt performance and should only be used for debugging. In general, an implementation of Python doesn't have to support stack frame inspection.

Comment: **DO NOT USE THIS**, it is very wrong!! It looks up variables using dynamic scoping rather than lexical scoping!!

Comment: This answer works for me (https://gist.github.com/thomasahle/c24b91f2bb19e853cc5ae58cf263b14a) but @user541686's answer doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer is very, very wrong—`f_back` gives the **caller**, not the lexically parent scope!

Python is lexically scoped, not dynamically scoped!

What you want can be done using the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52505101/541686):

```
def nonlocals():
    import inspect
    caller = inspect.currentframe().f_back
    return {k: v for k, v in caller.f_locals.items() if k in caller.f_code.co_freevars}
```

Note that this will return only names actually used in the function, not nonlocal variables that exist but aren't used.

Comment: ehm.. aren't you using `.f_back` above (the linked answer doesn't do this).

Comment: @thebjorn: Yes, that is fine. The linked answer doesn't need to do this because its caller has already called `inspect.currentframe()` and provided its starting stack frame, so the answer doesn't need to do that. However, over here I don't have the starting `frame` provided to me, so I need to obtain it myself by inspecting the stack. This is *entirely separate* from the variable lookup mechanism. What I'm *not* doing here is using the `.f_back` chain to look up the variables dynamically (see the `.f_back` inside the loop in the accepted answer), which is the problem with that answer.

Comment: Ah, I see. Can you solve the original problem too, i.e. get a dict of all lexically scoped variables that are not in `globals()` and not in `locals()`?  Meaning, return `{'x':33}` from the OPs code without needing to pull the variable into locals by using it (here by calling print) or declaring it with a nonlocal statement?

Comment: @thebjorn: Unfortunately as far as I know it's not possible, because the enclosed function doesn't store a reference to its enclosing function. It only stores references to the cells containing the closure variables directly, which only occurs for variables that are in a closure. In fact, if the variables aren't in closures, then they may not even exist at this point. (Put another way, this would require a Python program to store its own execution history indefinitely, never discarding it because someone may later decide to look up variables from some dead frame.)