# How to check if a variable with a given name is nonlocal?

Tags: python, python-3.x, stack-frame, python-nonlocal

Given a stack frame and a variable name, how do I tell if that variable is nonlocal? Example:

```
import inspect

def is_nonlocal(frame, varname):
    # How do I implement this?
    return varname not in frame.f_locals  # This does NOT work

def f():
    x = 1
    def g():
        nonlocal x
        x += 1
        assert is_nonlocal(inspect.currentframe(), 'x')
    g()
    assert not is_nonlocal(inspect.currentframe(), 'x')

f()
```

Comment: If is is ***non*** local, should `varname` the be in `frame.f_locals`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: I had a typo there, I fixed it in a minute or two.

Comment: related/duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22438219/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-dict-object-with-nonlocal-variables

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Related, though not a duplicate. However, the answer there seems very, **very** wrong!! `f_back` gives the *caller*'s frame (dynamic scope), rather than the *definer*'s frame (lexical scope)!!!

Comment: note that I didn't close the question :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Yeah, thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the frame's code object's `co_freevars`, which is a tuple of the names of closure variables the code object uses:

```
def is_nonlocal(frame, varname):
    return varname in frame.f_code.co_freevars
```

Note that this is specifically closure variables, the kind of variables that the `nonlocal` statement looks for. If you want to include all variables that aren't local, you should check against `co_varnames` (local variables not used in inner scopes) and `co_cellvars` (local variables used in inner scopes):

```
def isnt_local(frame, varname):
    return varname not in (frame.f_code.co_varnames + frame.f_code.co_cellvars)
```

Also, don't mix things up with `co_names`, which is currently misdocumented. The `inspect` docs say `co_names` is for local variables, but `co_names` is kind of an "everything else" bin. It includes global names, attribute names, and several kinds of names involved in imports - mostly, if execution is expected to actually need the string form of the name, it goes in `co_names`.